# NoMethodError when attempting to access attribute of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am having a bit of trouble understanding why I am unable to access attributes of an associated model in Rails using wrapper methods. I have a model spec failing, here's an illustration:

[image]

Here is a short illustrative list of the associated files:

```
event.rb

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author, :away_team_score, :details, :event_on, 
                  :home_team_score, :name, :title, :type, :home_team_id,
                  :away_team_id, :winner, :user_id

  validates_presence_of :author, :name, :title, :event_on, :type

  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :medias, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team"

  scope :by_user, ->(user_id) {where(user_id: user_id).order("name")}
  scope :by_team, ->(team_id) {where(team_id: team_id).order("sport_type")}
  scope :by_score, -> {select(:home_team_score, :away_team_score, :winner)}
  scope :upcoming_events, -> {where("event_on >= ?", 1.minute.from_now)}
  scope :past_events, -> {where("event_on < ?", 1.minute.ago)}
  scope :recent, -> {where("event_on > ?", 3.days.ago).limit(3)}

  def winner
    if home_team_score > away_team_score
      home_team_name
    elsif home_team_score == away_team_score
      "#{home_team_name} #{away_team_name}"
    else
      away_team_name
    end
  end

  private
  def home_team_name
    home_team.name
  end

  def away_team_name
    away_team.name
  end
end

team.rb

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :sport_type, :university_id

  belongs_to :university

  validates_presence_of :name, :sport_type
end


event_spec.rb - only the failing spec.

context "a winning home team" do
  it "returns the home team name" do
    event = Event.new
    event.home_team_score = 20
    event.away_team_score = 10
    expect(event.winner).to eq event.home_team_name
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems that the object is nil, check that object is not nil.

Comment: I have a team object saved in my database, confirmed with a call from the console. Is that what you meant by checking that the object isn't nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the my_object.try(:method) : it will not raise an error if my_object is nil

```
def home_team_name
  home_team.try(:name)
end

def away_team_name
  away_team.try(:name)
end
```

If you want to display a value if no away/home team is associated, use the double pipe:

```
def away_team_name
  away_team.try(:name) || 'No away team associated'
end
```

---

An alternative, more explicit:

```
def away_team_name
  if away_team.present?
    away_team.name
  else
    'No away team associated'
  end
end
```

Or the short version:

```
def away_team_name
  away_team.present? ? away_team.name : 'No away team associated'
end
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Yoshiji. My objects weren't present.

Answer (score 1):

In your spec, you have no association built between the event and the teams. You call `Event.new` to get a new event, but then never build an association between `event` and any teams. So, of course, `home_team` and `away_team` are both nil on that Event instance.

You need better setup in your spec.

```
it "returns the home team name"  
  event = Event.new(home_team_score: 20, away_team_score: 10)
  event.home_team = Team.new(name: 'foo')
  expect(event.winner).to eq 'foo'
end
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I missed the assignment step as well. Thanks!